# Python/Django UserProfile.objects.get()

Tags: python, django, django-1.6

In my view i got the code below, and my question is why after i got the user's info from the `User.objects.get(username=request.user)`, the `UserProfile.objects.get` returns None, what else happens in the try statement that fails? I am Django beginner so forgive my stupidity.

```
def profile(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    cat_list = get_category_list()
    context_dict = {'cat_list': cat_list}
    u = User.objects.get(username=request.user)


    try:
        up = UserProfile.objects.get(user=u)
    except:
        up = None

    print u   #this one prints out the user
    print up  #this prints 'None'
    context_dict['user'] = u
    context_dict['userprofile'] = up
    return render_to_response('blog/profile.html', context_dict, context)
```

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    website = models.URLField(blank=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', blank = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Comment: You don't *know* `UserProfile` returns `None`, since you have a try/except block (it could throw an exception). Can you post your UserProfile model?

Comment: Catching *all* exceptions usually isn't a good idea. Find out what exception is raised to cause `up = None`.

Comment: have you imported `UserProfile` into views.py?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist no, his `UserProfile` class has a `user` field of type `User`

Comment: @JamieCockburn Yep I looked back up at the wrong line. Thanks.

Comment: Wait, no: this is why I am confused. What is `User.objects.get(username=request.user)` supposed to be doing? `request.user` is [already a User object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user). This should raise `User.DoesNotExist`.

Comment: I think (this is tutorial, so i am not 100 % sure) that request.user is checking the name of the logged in person for which the profile page is displayed

Comment: @SuburbanFilth no, request.user *is* a `User`, as @Two-BitAlchemist says

Comment: ...which means that it should be `User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)`

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist it's also entirely superfluous! :)

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist that doesn't work

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Exception?

Comment: well, after i changed the  username=request.user to username=request.user.username it did not help my problem.

Comment: `request.user` is a user object, no need to fetch it from the database again. Also, if you wanted to fetch the object from the db, `user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)`, or what I prefer `user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)`.

In any case, just remove the code fetching user from the database and everything should be fine.

Comment: Oh, and since there is a `OneToOne` from `UserProfile` to `User`, you can simply fetch the `UserProfile` object using `request.user.userprofile`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question because someone else might end up in the same situation...

When i removed the try/except block I saw that i have to add

```
`AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = AppName.UserProfileClassName`
```

in my case

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = blog.UserProfile`
```

after I added it I tried again, but got `UserProfile matching query does not exist` error which is shown if u try to login with your admin account, so after I logged in with a normal account everything WORKED!

Answer (score 0):

Why is it that you think there should definitely exist a `UserProfile` related to that `User`?  There is no guarantee that there is.

You should follow the instructions in the documentation to correctly setup a [`UserProfile`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) class, and your view code can be simplified to this:

```
def profile(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/profile.html', {'cat_list': get_category_list(),
                                                 'user': request.user,
                                                 'profile': user.get_profile(),
                                                 })
```

If you want to do something special if a profile does not exist:

```
def profile(request):
    try:
        profile = user.get_profile()
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        profile = None
    return render(request, 'blog/profile.html', {'cat_list': get_category_list(),
                                                 'user': request.user,
                                                 'profile': profile,
                                                 })
```

Comment: I am just following the tutorial, not assuming anything... brb in 10 mins to accept the ans if it works

Comment: from what i see in django 1.6 there is no .get_profile() method, so any other suggestions ?

Comment: It's been in there since 1.2.  Did you follow the instructions in the documentation I linked to?